# Subquery to extract values from 4 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Some people told me this is not a very difficult one but unfortunately I can't really figure it out. I have the following tables

```
Person

**ID_Pers** | PersName | City | State | Phone | Email

1950901123893  Michael   Houston Texas  ---     ----

Student

**ID_student** | *ID_Pers* | entry_year | status | exit_year

A123           1950901123893  2014       finished   2017

Subject

**ID_subject** | Subject_name | credit_number | courses | laboratories

Exams

*ID_student* | *ID_subject* | **exam_date** | final_grade
```

The bold ones are primary keys while the ones that are italicized are foreign keys. I have to extract the students that have passed **at least** the exams that Michael has passed. I know I have to use subqueries in which I first select the exams that Michael has passed, then select the students that have passed those exams at least. I am having difficulties with this assignment. Can anyone assist me, please?

Comment: Please add more data. Currently I would SELECT only Michael and the problem is solved. Because there is just Michael.

Comment: How do we determine that Michael passed an exam? Is it based on a grade? There is no fail/pass indicator

Comment: Well it would be WHERE grade >=5.
I know I have to include
SELECT * from Exams
INNER JOIN student ON student.ID_student = exams.ID_student
INNER JOIN person ON student.ID_Pers = person.ID_pers
WHERE exams.final_grade >=5 AND person.PersName = "Michael"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Exams
INNER JOIN student ON student.ID_student = exams.ID_student
INNER JOIN person ON student.ID_Pers = person.ID_pers
WHERE exams.final_grade >=5 AND person.PersName = "Michael"
```

I know this is to basically select the exams that Michael has passed. But I need something before it to extract the other people which have passed at least the ones he passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the students that have passed the Exams (any exams) and then JOIN the result with the exams fetched in your query. Your final Query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * from Exams A
INNER JOIN student ON student.ID_student = exams.ID_student
INNER JOIN person ON student.ID_Pers = person.ID_pers
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * from Exams
INNER JOIN student ON student.ID_student = exams.ID_student
INNER JOIN person ON student.ID_Pers = person.ID_pers
WHERE Exams.final_grade >=5 AND person.PersName = "Michael") B ON A.ID_Subject = B.ID_Subject AND A.exam_date = B.exam_date
WHERE A.final_grade >=5;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I kind of adapted what you wrote into something similar and it worked. The only problem is that if for example Michael has passed an exam in Maths and English Literature and a guy David has passed the exam in Math, it will show Michael and David. But David should not qualify because he only passed 1 exam that Michael did, and not both. So I need a further condition somewhere that selects only the people who have **at least** passed the exams that Michael has.